# Gnome-music not scanning music folder

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.10, music-player

I'm using ubuntu 14.10 and I installed gnome-music but it is not scanning the music folder automatically, do you know if it is a bug or if I have special things to do ?
Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-music/+bug/1594104

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that all the miners in your tracker-control are on.

Type

```
tracker control
```

in terminal to check that. If the miners are off then switch them on using:

```
tracker control -s
```

Comment: In 17.10, tracker does not have a "control" command.  Now you need: `tracker daemon -s`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's tracking the correct folder by installing the Search & Index tools. You can use the Software Centre, or with this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tracker-gui tracker-utils
```

Additionally, I'd recommend telling Tracker not to look at the Videos and Downloads directory, and filter out '*.jpg' files. This is based on [this thread for Arch Linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1406269#p1406269).